# Offset a post in the loop, with using PageNavi Plug-in

Tags: pagination, loop, offsets

I am trying to offset 1 post in my main loop, I have tried a few things Like query_posts() etc  etc, and i can get the offset to work but my pagination ends up not working , I am using the PagNavi plug in , Any Help would be awesome , the Code is pretty generic , thanks again!

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php query_posts('offset=1');?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

//Content

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of query mechanics either `$paged` or `$offset` is used, but not both at the same time. Basically if you want custom offset then it is assumed that you do not want pagination.

You would probably need to hook into `post_limits` and change generated `LIMIT` SQL to adjust offset, unless there is an easier way that I am missing.

Comment: thank you for the feed back! was not aware of that, Ill keep searching